# Whipper: Snap package error

Tags: snap, cd-ripping

does anyone have any experience of the CD ripper, Whipper?

I had 0.7.2 running fine from a package (this one: https://launchpad.net/~spvkgn/+archive/ubuntu/whipper) but thought I'd upgrade to a newer one available as a snap.

I uninstalled the traditional package and the snap installed fine. Every time I try to run it though, it seems to run into a permissions error from denied access to the .config directory. A bit of Googling suggested installing with the --classic flag helped with a different snap with a similar error. Gave it a try but it didn't help here.

I can see from my other snaps they normally make their own .config in the ~/snap directory for the package. Could this be a faulty snap? It is a beta...

Anyone out there got it working?

FYI, this is the error I get, in full, when I try to run whipper:

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/whipper/23/bin/whipper", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('whipper==0.8.0', 'console_scripts', 'whipper')()
  File "/snap/whipper/23/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whipper/command/main.py", line 22, in main
    server = config.Config().get_musicbrainz_server()
  File "/snap/whipper/23/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whipper/common/config.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/snap/whipper/23/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whipper/common/config.py", line 47, in open
    with codecs.open(self._path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  File "/snap/whipper/23/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 898, in open
    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/home/xyzzy/.config/whipper/whipper.conf'
```

Comment: Create the directory yourself? `mkdir --mode=0700 --parents /home/xyzzy/.config/whipper`, or check the existing directory's ownership and permissions with `ls -ld /home/xyzzy/.config/whipper /home/xyzzy/.config/whipper/wipper.conf`

Comment: Fantastic! That did the trick. I tried editing the permissions right clicking and using the GUI but it (or more probably me...) must have borked it. Thanks!

Comment: I've transformed my comment into an Answer. Please click the Accept button, so I'll gain points and eventually Rule the World.

Comment: Thanks,  waltinator. Thought that was it because it started but threw the same error when it tried to write the config file. I 777'd but still no joy. When I was looking for an answer before I had read that snaps don't get access to . directories. Clearly it can see the .config folder because your suggestion of creating a new folder there did something but the snap package is a beta... wondering if it's just a broken package. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've abandoned my attempts to get the snap to work. I have Whipper working so I thought I'd post the alternative method here.

I installed it via docker, as per the instructions here: https://github.com/whipper-team/whipper#docker

Docker had some issues but I found a guide which fixed it here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket

Not sure if it was `sudo groupadd docker` and `sudo usermod -aG docker xyzzy` that fixed docker or `sudo chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock` or both.

Once I ran all three commands I was able to run `docker pull whipperteam/whipper` then add the alias and it whipper now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create the directory yourself?

```
mkdir --mode=0700 --parents /home/xyzzy/.config/whipper
```

or check the existing directory's ownership and permissions with

```
ls -ld /home/xyzzy/.config/whipper /home/xyzzy/.config/whipper/wipper.conf
```

And ensure `xyzzy` has write access.

Comment: Thanks! My apologies, though. With my earlier comment it looks like I jumped the gun. I deleted my old config folder and set a new one up with using your suggestion and the program started but it then throws the same error when it tries to write the config file.

I then tried:

'code' chmod -R 777 /home/xyzzy/.config/whipper

Unfortunately even that still gave the same permission denied error to the whipper.config file.

Thanks for the help, though! Feels like a step forward.